# What to do with leftover gin soaked clementines?

Tags: recommendations, gin

I'll start off with saying I'm not looking for a recipe or a list of ideas, as I know that's outside the scope of this SE, but if my question is too close to those lines, I won't take it personally if this is closed!

I usually have left over boosy fruit such as sloes, rubarb and etc and I make them into a boozy pie! But this year I made a spiced clementine gin.

The clementines are not pealed but are cut into 8ths. I'm wondering if there is any idea about how to use these? Maybe a jam, would you still taste the gin?

Comment: "You drank yourself into a slow-mo,
And made an angel in the snow,
Anything to pass the time,
And keep that song out of your mind. - 

Oh my darling, oh my darling, oh my darling
Clementine"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What to do with leftover gin soaked clementines?**

You could make jam with them if you have enough to do it with. The alcohol would obviously be evaporated off. The gin would give it a distinct flavour to the jam.

As for myself, I would mix them with a [fruit cocktail](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_salad) and eat them with ice cream after dinner. I have done this occasionally with and without ice cream for dessert.

Comment: I don't really eat dessert often so I suppose I was more looking for a way to preserve them! Note also that they still have the skins on and I think would be pretty tricky to peal as they are! Thanks for answering my question about the jam though, I think a gin marmalade would go down well :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm late with this answer, but there are a lot of things to do with leftover fruit that's been soaked in alcohol! Applying ideas in [this article](https://letsplayadrinkinggame.com/blog/8-fun-ways-use-leftover-alcohol-soaked-fruit/) about leftovers makes me think you could:

1. Cut off the peels and simmer the fruit with some sugar to use in desserts,
2. Do something similar but for a glaze on meat (boozy citrus + chicken sounds pretty good),
3. Use the clementines in a smoothie (if the peels have become soft enough they might blend right in),
4. Freeze pieces of the clementines in ice cubes to use in cocktails later (they'll look pretty and give the cocktail flavor as they melt)

Other ideas: https://letsplayadrinkinggame.com/blog/8-fun-ways-use-leftover-alcohol-soaked-fruit/